# Why does this work different in IE than it does in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code in an html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
    function industry(industryid)
    {
        if(industryid==0)
        {
            document.getElementById("SubIndustry").style.visibility="Hidden";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("SubIndustry").style.visibility="Visible";
        }
    }
</script>
```

This code is used here:

```
<div class="Question">
             2. What is the primary nature of your business?
        </div>

        <div class="Answer">
            <input type="radio" name="q2" class="Button" value="1-1" onchange='industry(0)' />
            Manufacturing/Logistics
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q2" class="Button" value="1-2" onchange='industry(0)' />
            Government/Schools
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q2" class="Button" value="1-3" onchange='industry(1)' />
            Commercial/Service/Medical/Retail/Other
        </div>

        <div id="SubIndustry">
            <div class="Question">
                Services Sub Industry
            </div>

            <div class="Answer">
                <input type="radio" name="q2-1" class="Button" value="135-55" />
                Healthcare
                <br />
                <input type="radio" name="q2-1" class="Button" value="135-56" />
                Other
            </div>

        </div>
```

Essentially this is what is supposed to happen: the `SubIndustry` div starts out invisible, and when someone selects the third industry option "Commercial/Service/Medical/Retail/Other" then the `SubIndustry` div appears.  If they click off of the third industry it disappears.

This is how it's working in Firefox, but in IE8 it's not.  It's acting like it's a "turn" behind.  so when I click on the third industry, nothing happens, but if i click of then SubIndustry shows up.  If I then click away it disappears again.

So, why is this working different in IE8 than Firefox?

Comment: Try using `onclick` instead of `onchange`

Comment: Remember that IE8 is not standard compliant, however I don't know exactly why this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be some bug because once you select the third option it is not making div visible but the very time you click **outside somewhere else** the div shows up!!!!!

I have modified the code and it works:-

```
<div class="Answer">
    <input type="radio" name="q2" class="Button" value="1-1" onclick="industry(0)" />
    Manufacturing/Logistics
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="q2" class="Button" value="1-2" onclick="industry(0)" />
    Government/Schools
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="q2" class="Button" value="1-3" onclick="industry(1)" />
    Commercial/Service/Medical/Retail/Other
</div>
```

Comment: oh i see, onclick instead of onchange